# material-ui autocomplete custom value

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, use-state

I don't understand why autocomplete clearing selected value, but logic for select value work excelent?
sandbox:
[sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-haslett-jhguy?file=/src/App.tsx)

Comment: I want to have selected value whitch type is be string or null. On the other side i want to have array of objects for options list. Like that

Comment: Remove the value prop from AutoComplete. The component will internally set it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sir.

You should use `inputValue` for AutoComplete, not `value` property.

```
...
<Autocomplete
        inputValue={selectedValue ? selectedValue  : ''}
        options={optionsList}
...
```